# Does Spring Tools Suite 3.8.3 support groovy grails?

Tags: grails, groovy

i want to develop with groovy/grails and need a IDE. I found older versions of STS supported groovy/grails. Does Spring Tools Suite 3.8.3 support groovy/grails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grails support in STS (Groovy/Grails Tools Suite, actually) ended in version 3.6.4 ([source](https://spring.io/tools/ggts)).

Answer (score 0):

You need only groovy support in your IDE, as starting from Grails 3.0 all project are plain gradle projects